# How do I construct a list with numbers like this?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

How do I construct a list like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
```

Where I run `command 15` or something. Or if I specify `100` it would make it with 100 numbers or `10000` and it would make it like this but 10000 numbers.

It should be five numbers on each line (as seen above).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you simply do

```
seq 1 n | xargs -n 5 echo
```

n being the number you want to reach

If your OS has bash but not seq, here is an alternative (thx to @cuonglm and @jimmyj for their remarks)

```
echo {1..n} | xargs -n5
```

(you may have to be careful when reaching **very** high number with that one, depending on the OS and bash version, and if bash actually tried to expand first or in that case is clever enough to feed little by little without trying to fit the whole 1..n as a string in memory and feed that to echo...)

And thanks to cuonglm and StephaneChazelas, I add an alternative that is very, very less CPU heavy than my first xargs solution (in which xargs calls /bin/echo, instead of being able to use the shell's builtin, every 5 numbers) (it's probably similar to the 2nd one where xargs doesn't invoke echo) :

```
printf '%s %s %s %s %s\n' {1..n}
```

That 2nd and 3rd solution differs from the 1st in that the shell have first to expand 1..n, before printf (or xargs) can start printing, if I'm not mistaken... so it starts later (especially if n is big)... And **could** reach some limits (line length, or memory, depending on the implementation and the OS) if n is very big.

Comment: +1 Far better readable than my solution. The first `1` in `seq 1 15` is not really necessary.

Comment: `echo` isn't necessary either.

Comment: Even better: `echo {1..100} | xargs -n5`

Comment: I agree with both remarks, but I much prefer to let them there : it's far more readable and portable to show how it really works (than just how it could be "golfscripted" to fit this particular example starting at 1 and only displaying numbers) ^^ (teach a person to fish /vs/ give this specific fish)

Comment: @jimmij : ok for bash (which indeed is specified here) but still I prefer to help portability (even if my solution is (maybe) a tiny bit less efficient as echo is bash builtin.. And I don't know if {1..n} is more efficiently done in bash than in seq)

Comment: @OlivierDulac: `seq` is on GNU system only. You can have `bash` on other *nix.

Comment: @cuonglm: indeed... I'll add the alternative. Thanks

Comment: I have seq on my OS X, which is mainly based of off FreeBSD.

Comment: @cuonglm, `bash` is GNU only. There's no non-GNU implementation on `bash`. `seq` originated in Plan9. There are several implementations. A similar `seq` command was added to GNU sh-utils (now merged into coreutils) in 1996. BSDs commands have had one since 2005 (starting with NetBSD). GNU coreutils, like `bash` have been ported to most systems.

Comment: That will fork a process and execute /bin/echo for every five arguments, so is going to be quite bad from a performance point of view. (try `seq 100 | strace -fe execve xargs -n5`)

Comment: `{1..n}` originated in `zsh` and was only relatively recently added to `ksh93` and `bash`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas and cuonglm: thanks for the comments, I'll add the printf alternative (less heavy, indeed)

Answer (score 8):

Pure `coreutils`:

```
$ seq 15 | paste - - - - - 
1   2   3   4   5
6   7   8   9   10
11  12  13  14  15
```

Pure perl:

```
$ perl -e '@a=1..15; while($i<=$#a){print "@a[$i..$i+4]\n";$i+=5}'
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
```

GNU grep (shamelessly [stolen from @1_CR](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/166181/22222)):

```
$ echo {1..15} | grep -oP '(\d+ ){4}\d+'
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
```

If you don't mind leading 0s:

```
$ echo {01..15} | fold -sw 16
01 02 03 04 05 
06 07 08 09 10 
11 12 13 14 15
```

And if you do:

```
$ echo {01..15} | fold -sw 16 | sed 's/0\([1-9]\) /\1 /g'
1 2 3 4 5 
6 7 8 9 10 
11 12 13 14 15
```

---

Any of these can be made into a function that takes a number as input and prints the corresponding list. For example,

```
printnums(){
 seq $1 | paste - - - - - 
}
```

You can then run

```
$ printnums 30
1   2   3   4   5
6   7   8   9   10
11  12  13  14  15
16  17  18  19  20
21  22  23  24  25
26  27  28  29  30
```

Comment: @DisplayName you can copy/paste the lines from my example directly into your terminal, that will make the function available to that terminal. Alternatively, add the lines to your shell's initialization file (`~/.bashrc` if you're running bash) and they will be available to all terminals. The `$1` is simply the first argument given to the function. For more details see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Functions).

Comment: Yet another example with column: `echo -e "\n"{1..100} | column -c40 -x`

Comment: @jimmij damn! I knew I was missing one!  Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: Why put all of these in one answer?

Comment: @Sparr why would I split them up? It just clutters the site with more answers than needed and stinks of rep whoring.

Comment: So they can be voted up or down separately. If you had the top voted answer, there'd be no way for a reader to know which solution in your answer was the best.

Comment: @Sparr none of them are "the best". The idea is to offer various alternatives for anyone who sees the question. I would only post two answers on the same question if they were radically different approaches. This is just using classic *nix tools. All of the answers are good really. Anyway, I dunno, I just don't really tend to post multiple answers on the same post. I'd rather have them all together.

Comment: Almost every answer to this question is "just using classic *nix tools".

Comment: @Sparr I really don't understand what point you are trying to make. I tend to avoid splitting my answers into multiple posts unless they suggest radically different approaches. Here, there's no one method that is "best". It is a matter of choice. Adding each as a separate answer would just clutter up the thread with more answers than are necessary and would help no one, the only beneficiary would be myself since people might upvote each separately. I find that a form of gaming the system and angling for extra rep and tend to avoid it. Perhaps we should take this to [meta].

Comment: @Sparr you made me realize that we don't seem to have a clear consensus on the multiple answers here. I also realized I came on a bit strong there, I'm sorry, I didn't mean to be aggressive. Anyway, I started [a discussion](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/3247/22222) on meta. You might want to post your view.

Answer (score 5):

With `printf` and [brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html):

```
printf '%s %s %s %s %s\n' {1..15}
```

Answer (score 4):

With `zsh`:

```
$ print -aC5 {1..15}
1   2   3   4   5
6   7   8   9   10
11  12  13  14  15

$ autoload zargs # if not in ~/.zshrc
$ zargs -n 5 {1..15} -- echo
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15

$ printf '%s %s %s %s %s\n' {1..15}
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
```

(that latter one also works in recent versions of ksh93 or bash).

Answer (score 2):

using looping :

```sh
for x in {1..15};do echo -n "$x ";if [ $(($x%5)) -eq 0 ];then echo ; fi done
```

output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 
6 7 8 9 10 
11 12 13 14 15
```

Comment: `if ! ((x%5)); then echo` or `if ((x%5 == 0)); then echo`

Comment: whats new?? here??

Comment: `[ $(($x%5)) -eq 0 ]` is unnecessarily verbose.

Comment: its not unnecessary, you can do like this or can be done in your way its just different way

Answer (score 2):

With `awk` you can say:

```
seq 15 | awk 'ORS=NR%5?FS:RS'
```

It returns:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
```

Basically, it changes the output record separator (line separator) by either a field separator (space, as default) or a record separator (new line, as default). So if the number of line is multiple of `5`, a new line is added; otherwise, a space.

I wrote a broader explanation in a similar question: [bash/sed/awk/etc remove every other newline](https://serverfault.com/a/634389/200076).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `seq`, `tr` and `sed`:

```
seq 15 | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/\([0-9]* [0-9]* [0-9]* [0-9]* [0-9]* \)/\1\
/g'
```

Or as an optimised combination of the answers by Olivier, Benoit and me (in his comments):

```
seq 15 | xargs -n 5
```

Comment: You don't need `tr`, use `seq -s" " 15` instead.

Answer (score 1):

All the elegant solutions were taken...so with GNU `awk` and `bash`

```
echo {1..15} | awk -v RS='[[:space:]]' '{ORS=NR % numcols?RT:"\n"; print}' numcols=5
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
```

or with GNU `grep`

```
echo {1..15} | grep -oE '([[:digit:]]+[[:blank:]]+){4}[[:digit:]]+'
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
```